# replica set in MongoDB using docker, primary has error and stops being primary when another member is added to the set

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have two docker containers running a mongo instance each, they were initialized like this:

```
docker run --name mongodb-shard-1-node-1 -d -v mongodb-shard-1-node-1:/data/db -p 27031:27017 mongo --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

when i do `docker inspect mongodb-shard-1-node-1` it shows the ip 172.17.0.2

```
docker run --name mongodb-shard-1-node-2 -d -v mongodb-shard-1-node-2:/data/db -p 27020:27017 mongo --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

when i do `docker inspect mongodb-shard-1-node-2` it shows the ip 172.17.0.4

So i proceed to access `mongodb-shard-1-node-1` by using `docker exec -it mongodb-shard-1-node-1 mongo` and i initialize it as the primary member like this:

```
rs.initiate()
{
    "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
    "me" : "ee3c41ef76b2:27017",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Then I proceed to add the `mongodb-shard-1-node-2` to this member for it to work as a secondary member, at first it looks like it worked:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add("172.17.0.4:27017")
{ "ok" : 1 }
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-05-20T01:04:02.095Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "members" : [ervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
            {       "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "ee3c41ef76b2:27017",
                    "state" : 1,,
                    "uptime" : 27,PRIMARY",
                    "optime""ts" : Timestamp(1463706237, 1),
                    },      "t" : NumberLong(1)
                    "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-05-20T01:03:43Z"),
                    "self" : truen" : 2,
            {,
                    "name" : "172.17.0.4:27017",
                    "state" : 0,,
                    "uptime" : 4,"STARTUP",
                    "optime""ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                    },      "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-05-20T01:04:01.187Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            }       "configVersion" : -2
    "ok" : 1
}
```

but right away it fails for some reason and i have no idea why, here's what i get:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
2016-05-20T01:04:18.007+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error doing query:
failed: network error while attempting to run command 'replSetGetStatus' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
DB.prototype.runCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:135:1
DB.prototype.adminCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:153:16
rs.status@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1090:12
@(shell):1:1

2016-05-20T01:04:18.012+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2016-05-20T01:04:18.018+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) ok
rs0:SECONDARY
```

What is wrong? How do I fix it?

**Edit**: just to clarify, i had already tried the connections between the containers by doing what [this part](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/) of the documentation says at: Test Connections Between all Members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Had my question answered here:
>   https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/139145/91866
>
> I'm gonna quote the whole answer:

Your primary is trying to auto-configure itself as `ee3c41ef76b2:27017` and that then resolves to the loopback (`127.0.0.1`) which is then not responding on the container as it expects. Depending on what the second container does to resolve `ee3c41ef76b2`, and especially it it does not resolve to 172.17.0.2, it will probably not be able to talk to the primary either.

Assuming you are correct about the connectivity (and you have verified that the instances are listening on the IP and not just the loopbasck) then you need to override the automatic detection and be explicit when you are calling `rs.initiate()`, something like this:

```
rs.initiate(
    {
      _id: "rs0",
      version: 1,
      members: [
         { _id: 0, host : "172.17.0.2:27017" },
         { _id: 1, host : "172.17.0.4:27017" }
      ]
    }
)
```